# Android api 21 app crash because of vector assets

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector, svg-android

I'm using svg format icons in my app. my application's minimum API level is 21 and target is 24. I knew that I can convert svg format icons into usual android vectors by android studio's "Vector asset" tool. ( which is accessible if you right-click on res/drawable directory -> new -> vector asset. )
Created vectors by this approach result well in android api higher than 21. but it causes app crashing in android 5 devices. though in google's documentation on vector assets it is said that vector assets are supported on api level 21 and higher.
Is there any idea that what can I do with this?
here's a sample of errors while app is trying to inflate an activity/fragment xml and a vector asset causes the crash:
    `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class ImageView`

Comment: Post your xml please

Comment: Post your xml and java code

Comment: This most certainly not version problem. Beside my experience of successfully using vector assets on API17 there is note in Android doc stating compatibility: "For backward-compatibility, Vector Asset Studio generates raster images of the vector drawable."

Comment: @Gotiasits I think that was the exact problem, I fixed it by converting the svg from an online convertor.

Comment: That's great! You can help others by answering your own question, explaining the solution and sharing tool you used.

Comment: @ArmanRamezanzadeh it is not a proper solution, online converter convert the svg with different format and tags in xml. I am facing same issue and using online converter also it is crashing for some vecctors

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But only in some svgs, others are drawing correctly. Don't know what's the issue!!!..Any ideaa